# How to get raw data from Alpaca Trade API BarSet?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I want to convert the results from `get_barset` in the `alpaca_trade_api` to a `dict` so that I can access the raw values.

```
{
    'AAPL': [
        Bar({   'c': 204.25,'h': 205.08,'l': 202.9,'o': 203.35,'t': 1562299200,'v': 14933941}), 
        Bar({   'c': 200.01,'h': 201.4,'l': 198.41,'o': 200.81,'t': 1562558400,'v': 21987224})
    ]
}
```

```
import alpaca_trade_api as tradeapi
import pandas as pd

bar= api.get_barset('AAPL', 'day', limit=2)
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(bar)
print(df)
```

The print output for this process is below. I'm not sure how to get the raw data from each `Bar`.

```
                                           AAPL
 0  Bar({   'c': 204.25,\n    'h': 205.08,\n    'l...
 1  Bar({   'c': 200.01,\n    'h': 201.4,\n    'l'...
```

I want my data to look like this in the end:

```
               c       h       l       o       t           v
bar1    204.25  205.08  202.9   203.35  1562299200  14933941
bar2    200.01  201.4   198.41  200.81  1562558400  21987224
```

Any and all help would be appreciated. Sorry if something is missing, this is post number one. Thank you for the help!

Comment: what is the data type of Bar ?

Comment: I think it is text. See the link below and go to get_barset to see how the data is formatted when brought in from the api. List to [link](https://github.com/alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api-python/blob/master/alpaca_trade_api/rest.py)

Answer (score 3):

There are two answers to this question.

1. This will create a Pandas dataframe

```
import alpaca_trade_api as tradeapi #see https://alpaca.markets/
import pandas as pd

api = tradeapi.REST(key_id, secret_key, base_url)

symbol = 'AAPL'

bar= api.get_barset(symbol, 'day', limit=60).df
```

2. This is a more brute force approach but does the samething.

```
import alpaca_trade_api as tradeapi #see https://alpaca.markets/
import pandas as pd

api = tradeapi.REST(key_id, secret_key, base_url)

symbol = 'AAPL'

bar= api.get_barset(symbol, 'day', limit=60)

c = []
h = []
l = []
o = []
t = []
v = []
idx = []

i = 0
for i in range(len(bar[symbol])):
    temp_c = c.append(bar[symbol][i].c) 
    temp_h = h.append(bar[symbol][i].h)
    temp_l = l.append(bar[symbol][i].l)
    temp_o = o.append(bar[symbol][i].o)
    temp_t = t.append(bar[symbol][i].t)
    temp_v = v.append(bar[symbol][i].v)
    temp_idx = idx.append(i)
    i = i + 1
df_bar_t = pd.DataFrame(t, idx,columns = ['Datetime'])
df_bar_c = pd.DataFrame(c, idx, columns = ['Close'])
df_bar_h = pd.DataFrame(h, idx, columns = ['High'])
df_bar_l = pd.DataFrame(l, idx, columns = ['Low'])
df_bar_o = pd.DataFrame(o, idx, columns = ['Open'])
df_bar_v = pd.DataFrame(v, idx, columns = ['Volume'])

mdf1 = pd.merge(df_bar_t,df_bar_c, left_index = True, right_index = True)
mdf2 = pd.merge(mdf1,df_bar_h, left_index = True, right_index = True )
mdf3 = pd.merge(mdf2,df_bar_l, left_index = True, right_index = True )
mdf4 = pd.merge(mdf3,df_bar_o, left_index = True, right_index = True )
mdf4 = pd.merge(mdf4,df_bar_v, left_index = True, right_index = True )
```

Answer (score 0):

Alpaca is still fairly new and unfortunately does not have the most explanatory documentation. Firstly, the result of `alpaca_trade_api.get_barset` is a `BarSet`. There *is* a `.df` attribute of `BarSet`, but neither the `BarSet` itself nor its `df` gives us direct access to the raw results.

Diving into the source code for the API's `BarSet`, which can be found [here](https://github.com/alpacahq/alpaca-trade-api-python/blob/cd22b3393aff8df214d867b6a4723a21ea34a3c0/alpaca_trade_api/entity.py#L138), we can see two things:

1. `BarSet` is a subclass of `dict`
2. `BarSet` has a `_raw` attribute

We can use this `_raw` attribute to access the raw data, which is a `dict`.

```
symbol = "AAPL"
bar_set = api.get_barset(symbol, "day", limit=5)._raw
```

Which outputs:

```
{
    'AAPL': [
        {'t': 1607317200, 'o': 122.31, 'h': 124.57, 'l': 122.25, 'c': 123.8, 'v': 72463180}, 
        {'t': 1607403600, 'o': 124.37, 'h': 124.98, 'l': 123.09, 'c': 124.33, 'v': 69695298}, 
        {'t': 1607490000, 'o': 124.53, 'h': 125.95, 'l': 121, 'c': 121.67, 'v': 99218318}, 
        {'t': 1607576400, 'o': 120.5, 'h': 123.87, 'l': 120.15, 'c': 123.22, 'v': 70011939}, 
        {'t': 1607662800, 'o': 122.43, 'h': 122.76, 'l': 120.55, 'c': 122.49, 'v': 75289233}
    ]
}
```

So, if you want to create a `pandas.DataFrame` with the raw values, you can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

symbol = "AAPL"
bar_set = api.get_barset(symbol, "day", limit=5)[symbol]._raw
df = pd.DataFrame(data=bar_set)
```

This gives us:

```
            t       o       h       l       c         v
0  1607317200  122.31  124.57  122.25  123.80  72463180
1  1607403600  124.37  124.98  123.09  124.33  69695298
2  1607490000  124.53  125.95  121.00  121.67  99218318
3  1607576400  120.50  123.87  120.15  123.22  70011939
4  1607662800  122.43  122.76  120.55  122.49  75289233
```